# Exchange Server 2010 and MySql

Tags: outlook, synchronization, mysql

I have an Exhange 2010 Server... with a public folder... that has a Contact List in it.

How would I access this via ODBC? Is it possible to do a "query" to pull the fields from Exchange Server into a MySql table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no ODBC driver for Exchange.  You need to write an application that reads the folder and then writes the data to a database.  Or, you need to automate the exporting of the folder to a CSV file so that you can use a text-file ODBC driver to read it.

RO

Comment: I eventually ended up making a custom C# console application that pulled from MySQL and updates the exchange contacts (reverse of the question, but same basic idea)